# Why would this toilet be running slowly?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I have [a Kohler AquaPiston](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CXS27BC) in my toilet tank that seems to be filling slower.

[image: Image of Kohler WaterPiston in toilet tank]

If I disconnect the hose going into it and just spray that directly in the tank, it fills up at a normal speed. When I connect the hose back to the water piston, it fills slowly.

I got a new one and installed it, and it still fills up slowly, which makes sense since the parts are all pretty simple and don't seem to have any build up or blockage.

I don't think anything is leaking from the yellow gasket at the base of the cylinder since once it's filled, it doesn't seem to turn back on briefly to refill ever, and since it's a new part, the gasket is in good shape.

I don't think it's the hose, the part to the left, etc because I can fill it quickly by disconnecting the hose and spraying that directly into the tank.

It seems like maybe the water that spraying in the cylinder is going down the drain instead of into the tank somehow, but I don't see how that'd be messed up since it's a new part.

**Is there anything I do to get the toilet to fill faster?**

Thanks!

Comment: Do not know that type, is it possible there is a made in restriction in it to slow the water?  Did you clean the seat before placing the new one in?